# How to show some part of file name

Tags: java, android

how to show some part of file name stored into SD Card, i am developing camera app in which i am capturing photo and storing into SD Card like this:

```
AU_201403251160_4_7_B-4-7-001.jpg
```

now i am showing all stored images into List, and i need to show only below code as file name instead of **AU_201403251160_4_7_B-4-7-001.jpg** :

```
     B-4-7-001.jpg
```

**code:**

```
  // ColImgName
    TextView txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ColImgName);
    strPath = ImageList.get(position).toString();

  // Get File Name
    fileName = strPath.substring( strPath.lastIndexOf('/')+1, strPath.length() );
    file = new File(strPath);
```

Comment: how many chars you want to save, how do you know its the B-4-7-001.jpg and not 7_B....

Comment: please make it clearer which part of the filename you need to keep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was very simple i made a small change, see below:

```
fileName = strPath.substring( strPath.lastIndexOf('_')+1, strPath.length() );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String[] a = "AU_201403251160_4_7_B-4-7-001.jpg".split("_");
    System.out.println(a[a.length - 1]);
```

output:

```
 B-4-7-001.jpg
```

This is minimal, you would obviously have some checks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String data = "AU_201403251160_4_7_B-4-7-001.jpg";
    System.out.println(data.substring(data.indexOf("-") - 1, data.length()));
```

output:

```
B-4-7-001.jpg
```

Comment: using your solution, i am getting only this: 001.jpg

Comment: @Moon in any way thats not possible..i am posted after checking only..recheck it..IndexOf() returns the first position of "-" the taht is between  B and 4 and from that too last character i am printing..

Answer (score 0):

```
String filename = "AU_201403251160_4_7_B-4-7-001.jpg";
System.out.println(filename.replaceFirst(".*_", ""));
```

output:

```
B-4-7-001.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String data = "AU_201403251160_4_7_B-4-7-001.jpg";
System.out.println(data.substring(data.lastIndexOf("_")+1));
```

output:

```
B-4-7-001.jpg
```